# Can't cat image from the videostream opencv

Tags: c++, opencv

Other questions did't help me, so i ask mine

Can't get any image from my videocam using the latest opencv library.

```
void ShowCam(int CameraToBeOpened)
{
int i = 0;
cv::Mat frame;
cv::VideoCapture cap(CameraToBeOpened);
cvNamedWindow("Camera", CV_WINDOW_NORMAL);
while (true) {
if (cap.read(frame))
    imshow("Camera", frame);
char c = cvWaitKey(50);
if (c == 27)
    break;
if (c == 32) {
    char filename[200];
    sprintf_s(filename, "\Test pictures\test_%d.jpg", i);
    i++;
    cv::imwrite(filename, frame);
    std::cout << "Image has been captured" << std::endl;
}
}
```

It doesn't generate mistakes, just can't find images in the folder.

Comment: Have you tried to debug the code and checked that the program actually reaches the line with imwrite()? Have you checked  if frame variable contains an image in the first place?

Comment: the code is OK. you need only change like `sprintf_s(filename, ".\\Test pictures\\test_%d.jpg", i);` or better `sprintf_s(filename, "test_%d.jpg", i);`

Comment: Thank you a lot! It works, if i change the path like `sprintf_s(filename, "test_%d.jpg", i)`